# Increase the Size of the Modal

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

Goal:
Make modal as a large modal by using class "modal-lg"

Problem:
Don't know how to solve it when I tried using the syntax code "modal-lg" in different places.

Info:
*I'm new in angular
*Using VS code and ngx-bootstrap

Thank you!

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-component-modal-ngx-bootstrap-not-working-ap7wnp

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code on the StackBlitz link provide by you.

Following are the changes in the **app.component.ts** file

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(template)">Create template modal</button>

<ng-template #template>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Modal</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
          <i>I want Full Name here. First name I am able to get, but last name i am not able to get form nested model here</i>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          Full name: {{person.fname}}
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="first Name" [(ngModel)]="person.fname"     #fname="ngModel">
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModalWithComponent()">Open Modal to enter last name</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</ng-template>
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: I tried your solution but I don't get modal as a large size.

Answer (score 0):

There is a size code in the ngx from memory.   LG, MD, SM.   Set that and it all works.